# VScode: why the log message doesn't show on the console/terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the log message, but the "log message" doesn't show:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work we need to apply it by pressing `enter`. It closed the log message popup, only a red square remains.

The log message then looks like this (when we hover the red square):

[image]

(Though, I don't understand why the log message show *before* the print)